# Printing Strings Using Multiple Files

Tags: c

I am new to C programming so bear with me here. I have been assigned a project where in which the user is prompted to enter a "part number, quantity, and price" when the user enters "0" the program ends, and the information is saved in a text file. A separate program gets compiled and then prints out what the user entered. Here is what the first program (save_inventory.c) prompts the user with.

```
This program stores a business inventory.

Please enter item data (part number, quantity, price): *3, 1, 2.4*

Please enter item data (part number, quantity, price): *1, 4, 3.0*

Please enter item data (part number, quantity, price): *0*

Thank you. Inventory stored in file inventory.txt.
```

And here is what the second program(display_inventory.c) is supposed to ouput:

```
Below are the items in your inventory:

Part#    Quantity     Item Price

3           1    $     2.40
1           4    $     3.00
2           4    $     1.30
```

I have the code working so far, the only issue is that when I use my display_inventory.c program, the last line of the input is printed twice. So 2, 4, $ 1.30 appears again. Here is the code for both programs:

save_inventory.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int pn, q;
float p;

 FILE *fp = fopen("inventory.txt", "wb");


printf("This program stores a business inventory.\n");

for(;;)
{
    printf("Please enter item data (part number, quantity, price): ");
    scanf("%d, ", &pn);
    if(pn == 0){break ;}
    scanf("%d, %f", &q, &p);

    fwrite(&pn , sizeof(pn) ,1, fp);
    fwrite(&q , sizeof(q),1 , fp);
    fwrite(&p, sizeof(p) , 1,fp);

}
printf("Thank you. Inventory stored in file inventory.txt.\n");
fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

And here is display_inventory.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int pn, q;
float p;

FILE *fp = fopen("inventory.txt", "rb");
printf("Part#\t Quantity\t Item Price");

for(;!feof(fp);)
{

    fread(&pn , sizeof(pn) ,1, fp);
    fread(&q , sizeof(q),1 , fp);
    fread(&p, sizeof(p) , 1,fp);
    printf("\n%5d\t %8d \t $%9.2f\n",pn,q,p);

}


fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Since I have spent a bit of time trying to figure this one out, I figured I'd ask if anyone has any tips on how to not have the last entry printed out twice.
Thank you!

Comment: Please, check the result of  operations such as `fopen`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first `fread()` add an

```
if (feof(fp))
{
    break;
}
```

What happens is that the first `fread` will trigger the end of file, so `pn` won't be changed. Then the second `fread` triggers end of file again, `q` also doesn't get changed. Then the 3rd `fread` yet again triggers eof, and `p` remains unchanged. `printf` will show the old values one more time.